# How to integrate AWEBER autoresponders concept in my own site

Tags: php

I am developing a site with a functionality of sending newsletters. I hereby like to integrate aweber autoresponders.

I am newbie to this aweber concepts.

Kindly advice me to do this integration.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for specific feedback it's best to contact AWeber's solutions team directly so we can give specific advice. Contact information can be found at the bottom of any page on our site.